# Typescript: checking truthiness of variable doesn't type-guard against undefined?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
class Base {}

function log(arg: number) {
    console.log(arg);
}

function fn<T extends typeof Base>(
    instance: Partial<InstanceType<T>>,
    key: keyof InstanceType<T>,
) {
    const val = instance[key];
    if (val) {
        log(val);
    }
}
```

TS Playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8C+AodAzArgO2ABcBLAez2hFIHMAKMAJ2oC5o8cBbAIwQYEoU6aMOjByEUiAQA6KnUbU+AbnQZs+ImQpY8AHgAq0BAA9CCPABMYhAJ4AHBKSxxEAPlpCRxPBEJgCCKwACowkYCC6AJI+fgH69ggGrq4ANJ7CANYINqxZNk7Q0b7+wAjxDklpAsjpouKE0ABu4dAAvNDexQEA2nkAuioiHc60zSDVtUNyo+HKtRgYQA

I get:

```
Argument of type 'InstanceType<T>[keyof InstanceType<T>] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Shouldn't `if (val)` guard against `undefined`? It works if I change it to `log(val ?? 0)`.

Also, I'm surprised `log(val ?? 0)` works. `val` could be a truthy value that's not a number, but `log()` expects a number. Why doesn't this throw an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is [well known](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31908). You may get some insight what's really happening inside the type checker from this [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42537#issuecomment-769955975):

> The core problem is that the narrowed type of fooAnchor is not really speakable. Its unnarrowed type is Partial<FooAnchorMap>[keyof TMap], which isn't a union that we can remove undefined and null from to produce some other type that would be provably-assignable to HTMLElement.

There is [work in progress](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/22348) to resolve it. But as of now you're left only with workarounds.

```ts
function fn<T extends typeof Base>(
    instance: Partial<InstanceType<T>>,
    key: keyof InstanceType<T>,
) {
    const val: InstanceType<T>[keyof InstanceType<T>] | undefined = instance[key];
    if (val) {
        log(val);
    }
}
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/weevgw)

And you'll get the correct error:  `Type 'InstanceType<T>[string]' is not assignable to type 'number'.`

Answer (score 0):

The `undefined` bit is a red herring; this is only being flagged because `strictNullChecks` is enabled which means unless you declare

```
function log(arg: number) {
    console.log(arg);
}
```

as

```
function log(arg: number | undefined) {
    console.log(arg);
}
```

it is going to complain whenever you pass anything in which may resolve to `undefined`. Disabling `strictNullChecks` will eliminate that error (though present others with the above code); alternatively guaranteeing that `undefined` is handled before being passed in (e.g. `?? 0`) will also work.

> Also, I'm surprised log(val ?? 0) works. val could be a truthy value
> that's not a number, but log() expects a number. Why doesn't this
> throw an error?

This should error if `val ?? 0` doesn't resolve to a number and `log()` expects a number, i.e. in the scenario you described where a truthy non-number is passed in. This fails correctly for me in the playground, do you have an example of this not working?

Comment: `it is going to complain whenever you pass anything in which may resolve to undefined` but it shouldn't be able to resolve to undefined because of the `if` statement